# iOS - Need a method to read the metadata of other apps currently running in device

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a method that will allow me to see what other apps are running on a device and display the apps name and category/subcategory (As listed in developer meta data).  Would also like (but not required) to have a way to capture/display the app icon of the apps that are running (of a certain category).

Does anybody know if any of the above is possible?  Don't know need to affect the other apps in any way - just need to be able to find/display the names and categories of the apps that are running in bg.

thanks for your help.

bp

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. That would break the sandbox restrictions. The closest you could get is to check the app delegate canUse for URI scheme. That doesn't cover all app but the big opens like Dropbox, Facebook, linked in all have URI schemes.